# Switched from Windows to Ubuntu and can't access files on previous "D:" drive

Tags: mount, filesystem, fdisk

So, I have two drives, the first one is a SSD and the second one is a HDD which I cannot access.

[image: disks]

I tried to mount it, but in the "disks" mount option it is greyed out and in `gparted`, it shows me an error

> Unable to detect file system

These are two images of the situation:

[image: gparted 1]
[image: gparted 2]

Is there a way of fixing this without installing Windows again?
Hdd info listed in `fdisk`:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors 
Disk model: TOSHIBA DT01ACA2
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EF53476A-EA19-11E5-85BD-408D5C37B70F
```

and this is a statistical result:

```
Device      Start        End          Sectors     Size   Type
/dev/sdb1   264192       3907028991   3906764800  1,8T   Microsoft basic data
```

Comment: Is this formatted as exfat?

Comment: @mchid I'm not 100% sure but I think it's ntfs.

Comment: @user68186 Im not dual booting, so the only way is to go to windows and try to convert :( . Thank you guys for help.

Comment: I see. Since you mentioned previous D: Partition, I assume it came partitioned like that with Windows 10 and it may be set as dynamic type at the factory. It's just a guess. If there is a live USB for Windows to try before installing, may be it can be fixed. I don't know

Comment: It's also possible that Windows 10 was in a hibernated state when you went to "shut down" Windows for the last time. By default Windows 10 doesn't actually close the disk and power down, but instead hibernates and leaves the disk in a strange state like this.

Comment: Can you manually mount read only? https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation If you keep an NTFS partition you either need Windows or at least a Windows repair disk. NTFS will need chkdsk, defrag  & maintenance which you cannot do from Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It seems when I installed ubuntu and tried to mount hdd it somehow deleted its filesystem file and I couldn't restore it even in Windows. Partition was RAW file and I recovered some of files from it but couldn't get images sadly :( . Luckily I had onedrive backup. Thank you guys for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try turning OFF the fast startup option in Windows as shown [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html). If it is turned on, Windows will not shut down properly. Also instead of doing shutdown in Windows, do a restart and power off before the GRUB comes (nasty work around). I have tried this method before and could access files in drives using Windows from Ubuntu.

Cheers!